# `\[` in code triggers LateX in preview

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, formatting, latex, search

When the code contains the characters `\[`, the preview shows everything else as LateX even though it is inside the `` section. This is how the preview looks like:
[image: first]

This is how the submission actually looks like:

[image: second]